# A set of non-isomorphic finite groups is a finite set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let F= set of all non-isomorphic groups of order n where n>=2. I want to show that F is a finite set.

I want to use the fact: Every group |G|=n is an isomorphic to a subgroup of Sn. But i don't know how.

Can anyone give me a direction please? Thank you

Comment: How many subgroups of $S_n$ are there? (Can there be infinitely many?)

Comment: How many distinct multiplication tables can you write down on a set of size $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that a group is finite iff it has a finite number of subgroups.

Comment: okay so i use the fact above to show that Sn has finite # of subgroups and all non-isomorphic groups in F are isomorphic to atleast one subgroup of Sn and therefore there are finitely many non-isomorphic groups in F, therefore F is a finite set!

Comment: Indeed so, just as Alex and Quinn already hinted in their comments.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help!!