# Number of distinct groups of order n upto isomorphism, for a fixed integer n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given any positive integer $n$, is the number of distinct groups of order $n$ upto isomorphism finite?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many binary operations can you think of in a set of $n$ elements? Forget group axioms for a while.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: It is finite. I dont know exactly how many?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422120/known-bounds-for-the-number-of-groups-of-a-given-order, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258753/a-set-of-non-isomorphic-finite-groups-is-a-finite-set

Comment: deibor, so you were able to answer the question yourself! Good! Oh, and the number is just $n^{n^2}$ as the operation is just a function from a set of size $n^2$ to a set of size $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Any such group is a subgroup of $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ elements. There are only finitely many such subgroups.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are finitely many maps $G\times G\to G$.

Comment: How can we know how many groups exist of a given order upto isomorphism?