# The number of groups of order n(upto isomorphism)is

Tags: group-theory

The number of groups of order $n$ (upto isomorphism)is

a)finite for all values of $n$

b)finite only for finitely many values of $n$

c)finite for infinitely many values of $n$

d)infinite for some values of $n$

I think option (b) is correct.please help me

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466395/number-of-distinct-groups-of-order-n-upto-isomorphism-for-a-fixed-integer-n

Comment: And hopefully you can choose more than one option because (a) implies (c) [and, less importantly, (b) implies (d)]  :-)

Answer (score 9):

Note that on a set $G$ with $n$ elements, there are $n^{n^2}$ maps $G \times G \to G$, hence there are at most $n^{n^2}$ non-isomorphic groups of order $n$.